# Making Maps of Individual US Counties in R

Tags: r, maps

I'm wondering how to make a map of ONLY a county in R, and if possible, how to do this without using a shapefile.

For example, I'd like to make a map of Los Angeles county in California. Is there anyway for me to call up a map of just LA county?

What I tried is to set `xlim` and `ylim` to manually "crop" the map that is displayed (finding the coordinates on Google Maps), but I'm looking for a easier way to make maps of counties.

Here's what I did to plot LA county:

```
map("county", interior=TRUE, regions="california",
    xlim=c(-119.023098 ,-117.435574), ylim=c(33.70319 ,34.941657))
```

And here's an example of the type of map that I'm looking for:

[image]

Suggestions on an easier way to create substantively the same map would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `regions` with the county name:

```
map("county", regions="california,los angeles")
```

Comment: I get "as_mapper(.f, ...) : argument ".f" is missing, with no default"

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `ggmap` to map the counties.
You could simply get a map of the county using a string:

```
library(ggmap)
la_county<-get_map('los angeles county')
ggmap(la_county)
```

Or you could use the x and y coordinates to center the map view:

```
library(ggmap)
la_county<-get_map(c(-118.2218,34.3582)) #or get_map(c(mean(-119.023098 ,-117.435574), mean(33.70319 ,34.941657)))
ggmap(la_county)
```

You can also adjust the basemap aesthetics and zoom level:

```
library(ggmap)
la_county<-get_map('los angeles county', zoom=9, type='toner')
ggmap(la_county)
```